# jQuery not working with select2 hiding instructions

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have 3 select2 boxes and the page requires for the other two to be disabled when one is used. I have the following code, however it doesn't work. When page loads, all select2's disappear (they're set as hidden inputs in HTML):

```
$("#collection-search").change(function(){
            if($(this).val())
                $("#subject-search").select2("enable", false);
                $("#special-search").select2("enable", false);
            else
                $("#subject-search").select2("enable", true);
                $("#special-search").select2("enable", true);
        });

        $("#subject-search").change(function(){
            if($(this).val())
                $("#collection-search").select2("enable", false);
                $("special-search").select2("enable", false);
            else
                $("#collection-search").select2("enable", true);
                $("special-search").select2("enable", true);
        });

        $("#special-search").change(function(){
            if($(this).val())
                $("#collection-search").select2("enable", false);
                $("#subject-search").select2("enable", false);
            else
                $("#collection-search").select2("enable", true);
                $("#subject-search").select2("enable", true);
        });
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I'm looking through FireBUG but nothing useful shows up. Only thing I can see is a syntax error in an "else" statement in jquery.min.js.

Comment: If your conditional statements have more than one line, use brackets or it will break.

Comment: Like this: `if($(this).val()){
                    $("#subject-search").select2("enable", false);
                    $("#special-search").select2("enable", false);}`?

Comment: Yes, otherwise the statement has no idea where to end

Comment: Ok that sorta works. Conditions are met correctly for the first and third select2, but when using the second one, only first select2 disables.

Comment: Edit your code, and you should also add in the HTML you are using. That will help.

Comment: Nevermind, missed a # in there. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As per comments, here is your code in answer form -- just had to add brackets. Glad it works!

```
$("#collection-search").change(function(){
        if($(this).val()) {
            $("#subject-search").select2("enable", false);
            $("#special-search").select2("enable", false);
        }
        else {
            $("#subject-search").select2("enable", true);
            $("#special-search").select2("enable", true);
        }
    });

    $("#subject-search").change(function(){
        if($(this).val()) {
            $("#collection-search").select2("enable", false);
            $("special-search").select2("enable", false);
        }
        else {
            $("#collection-search").select2("enable", true);
            $("#special-search").select2("enable", true);
        }
    });

    $("#special-search").change(function(){
        if($(this).val()) {
            $("#collection-search").select2("enable", false);
            $("#subject-search").select2("enable", false);
        }
        else {
            $("#collection-search").select2("enable", true);
            $("#subject-search").select2("enable", true);
        }
    });
```